# Jupyter Notebooks - checking library versions and testing for them

Tags: python, testing, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently testing some installs on Jupyter notebooks and I want to check the installed version of particular libraries/modules (e.g. numpy) and then run a test to confirm that version, preferably using doctest.

Example:

```
! python3 -m pip install numpy
<check installed version>
<test version using doctest>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Edit: this is being done under Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Type `pip3 list` in command prompt. It gives you version of all installed libraries

Comment: Looking to do this programmatically in the notebook itself, not through command prompt.

Comment: `import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)` Try this one in python